# Rollermouse middle button doesn't act as double-click anymore after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mouse, 22.04

I'd need ideas to solve an issue with my rollermouse middle-button. It should act as a double-click, but it's not after my recent upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04. Now it works as a normal single click.

I have Contour's Rollermouse Free3 product and the middle button used to work as double-click correctly in Ubuntu 20.04. I've tried using it with two different computers Ubuntu 22.04 installed and it still happens.

[image]

Any idea how I should start investigating this problem?